# Route53 not publishing records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a hosted zone in Route 53 for a registered domain with AWS. But I get no records for this hosted zone if I query this domain.

The records just suddenly stopped working. It did work before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My domain was suspended. You can check this by going into Route53 > Registered Domains > .

I missed the e-mail verification step. Inside that menu, you can resend the e-mail. After confirming my e-mail, my domain was up after some hours. It might be faster, but I didn't check.

Comment: Are you saying that this happened to you? Why was the domain suspended -- was it due to the missed email? Are you saying that the domain was working successfully but then stopped working? How long was the 'operational' period before it was suspended?

Comment: I changed my answer to my specific situation and incorporate the answers to your questions.